# Trying to understand the view method and general method calling in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a new to laravel and trying to understand where the view method comes from and what mechanism allows it to be shown in the web.php folder in laravel.
For example :

```php
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); })
```

I guess the view function is defined in some class. Bu which class is it and where is that class made reference to in order to access its method?
Thanks a lot if you can help me understanding this!

Answer (score 0):

In most IDEs you can hold CTRL and left-click the function to view it's definition. `view()` is not defined in a class. It comes from a file called `helpers.php`.

This file is included at the beginning, so its functions can be used afterwards.

PHP is not only object oriented. Procedural and object oriented programming can be mixed together.

Answer (score 0):

What I do usually in these cases is to search in the whole project (and remember to include `vendor` directory in your search) for: "function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME" because somewhere in PHP there must be that function declared, whether is in a class or in a simple `.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

`view()` method is a helper method inside `src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`. All the methods that declare here will be available everywhere inside Laravel application. You can check `view()` method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/eff2f054606e8251e59023a6f1a4f0fd773634de/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L960)

Comment: Hey thanks Phanna for your reply:)  what mechanism makes it possible to use these functions from the helpers.php file anywhere in the laravel framework?  Thanks :)

Comment: @FriedrichCoen All these helpers function has been registered in autoload composer.json so it will available for us to use. One more thing, they also used `if (! function_exists('function_name'))` to make sure all these function will not conflict with other function name


  check here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/eff2f054606e8251e59023a6f1a4f0fd773634de/composer.json#L94